# What is SQL Sever's default format for converting dates from strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-convert

I'm trying to work with a 3rd party application which stores dates (can be entered by the user, in some cases with little validation) in a varchar column, then uses `CONVERT( DATETIME, MY_COLUMN )` - without an explicit format - when it wants to use them as dates.  Ugh.

Unsurprisingly this often fails.  But not always.  What is SQL's default format for `CONVERT` if you don't specify one?  It appears to be 101 (i.e. mm/dd/yyyy), but is this always the case?  Does it depend on the database or server collation or some other setting?  The [MSDN CAST and CONVERT docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx) don't say.

We're using SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the default, it depends on the default language setting at the server or login level, which implicitly sets the `dateformat`, `datefirst`, as culture related settings. You can also change the defaults based on `login`. e.g.

```
alter login [aucuparia] with default_language=[british];
```

These can be changed at the session level with [**`set language`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174398.aspx), [**`set dateformat`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx), and [**`set datefirst`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx).

To see the language setting for the current connection:

```
select @@language;
```

To see settings for each language:

```
select langid, alias, DateFormat, DateFirst, months, shortmonths, days 
from sys.syslanguages;
```

Comment: I don't think `datefirst` is relevant to this question.

Comment: @RogerWolf I included it as part of the answer because it is also set implicitly by the language setting and effects the results of date and time functions concerning the `week` date part.